# Waiting for three seconds between HTTP requests to specific URL

Tags: scala, http, akka, spray

Using spray, I want to have a system that waits for some seconds between it sends two HTTP requests to specific URL, because I don't want to mess up the server's traffic for my app's auto connections. How do you do it? I can make it by putting the command in every place where  it needs to pause, but I figured it's not looking cool and hard to maintain afterwords. I would love if it can be abstracted into the level of `ActorSystem`. Thank you!

Comment: I would create a `Scheduler` that sends Ticks to myself every three seconds and when received make a HTTP request.

Comment: You could try a Throttle between the actor that initiates the request and the actor that makes the request. http://letitcrash.com/post/28901663062/throttling-messages-in-akka-2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very seasoned with Spray, but could you do a third bogus request (in between your two actual requests) with a "some seconds" timeout period? (or maybe 1/2 of "some seconds" to allow for the request retry doubling the actual time you end up waiting?) Sorry if this is unhelpful or incorrect, like I said I haven't worked with it much :/

Comment: Mmm, what I mean is that I'm going to use one system to send HTTP requests to any kind of servers, but when doing it to some of them that I specify by regex of the URL or something, then I want the system to be nice and polite.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a TimerBasedThrottler to throttle the messages an Actor receives. Here is a quick example of what you would need

```
// Actor that handles making the HTTP request
class MyRequestActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case url => makeRequest(url)
  }
}

// throttles to 1 message per second
val throttler = system.actorOf(Props(new TimerBasedThrottler(new Rate(1, (1.second))))
val requestActor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyRequestActor))

// register your actor with the throttler
throttler ! SetTarget(Option(requestActor))

// send messages to the request actor through the throttler
throttler ! "some/url"
```